# Can I create an array of unique words from two arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, set

I have two arrays in JavaScript, and I want to create a new array that contains only the unique values from both arrays. How can I do this in JavaScript?

```
const arr1 = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date', 'elderberry'];
const arr2 = ['cherry', 'date', 'elderberry', 'fig', 'grape'];
```

I've tried using the `concat` method to combine the arrays and then using a `Set` to remove duplicates, but that doesn't work because the `Set` considers arrays to be different objects even if they have the same values.

I've also tried using a `for` loop to iterate through both arrays and an `if` statement to determine whether each word already exists in the new array, but that seems wasteful and doesn't function if the arrays include a large number of duplicate words.

Can someone please point me in the direction of a more reliable and efficient JavaScript method for generating an array of distinct words from two arrays? I'm grateful.

Comment: Please show what you tried with `Set`; I'm sure it can be used to achieve your goal.

Comment: Welcome to [so] - Please take the [tour] and check out the [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question.  For starters, please include a [mre] of your efforts for faster troubleshooting

Comment: What's your expected output? Should it be the values that only appear in one of the arrays or all the values from both arrays, but only listed once?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please give it try?

```
const arr1 = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date', 'elderberry'];
const arr2 = ['cherry', 'date', 'elderberry', 'fig', 'grape'];

const mergedArr = [...new Set([...arr1, ...arr2])];

console.log(mergedArr); // Output: ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date', 'elderberry', 'fig', 'grape']
```

Comment: but 'date' is not unique, it should not be in the output (OR maybe I misunderstood the requirements)

Answer (score 0):

To get a set of unique strings, first concat the arrays into a single array using the spread (`...`) operator, and use the new array as the parameter to `Set`:

```js
const uniques = new Set([...arr1, ...arr2])
```

To convert the `Set` to an array:

```js
[...uniques]
```